# Tabulator: links with a label

Tags: javascript, php, html, tabulator

I'm currently building a table with Tabulator where I have a column "Link". Only some rows contain a URL and some don't (emtpy cell). I now want to have a clickable link which shows the text "Link".

I can either get 
- the entire URL as clickable link shown in the cell or
- show "Link" in all rows, even if there is no link available (which leads to "undefined" destination) or
- have the URL as plain text

My 'link' column is defined as follows:

```
{title:"Link", field:"link", formatter:"link", formatterParams:{target:"_blank",}},
```

The data I geht from my MySQL database is handled as follows:

```
  if($row->link != "") {
    echo "link:\"" . $row->link . "\", \n";
  }
```

It does not work (for me) to build a link in the echo part (it will be plain text later):

`echo "link:\"<a href=" . $row->link . ">Link</a>\", \n";`

Does someone know, how to set it up?

Comment: already read [this](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/format) ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/format#format-custom) to do this.

You could use the built in [Link Formatter Code](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/format.js#L164) as a starting point, and just add a bit more logic to handle your usage case

Answer (score 0):

@illuminarch: sorry, cannot add a comment to your question: Yes, but if I use a *label - a string representing the lable* this label will also be shown in cells where no URL is available.